# Features of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, document-repository

I am looking for a document repository solution (hosted internally, not cloud-based) that has the following set of features:

- Statuses: Users can set a status (pending, complete, etc) on the document. Notification system based on the status change.
- Workflows: Ability to define who the documents go to based on the different statuses. Be able to customize these workflows.
- Tagging: Users want to be able to tag different sections of a document with certain key words.
- Search: Ability to search for documents based on content within the document as well as for tags.
- Merging: Ability to select different pages and/or content within one document and merge that content to another document. Kinda like copy and paste, but more seamless.
- Archiving: We need to be able to archive documents in some way.
- Permission System: We want to limit document access to users based on roles (read, edit, delete, etc.)
- Real-time collaboration: Users should be able to view documents at the same time.

I know that SharePoint has support for at least some of these features, but I am not sure which ones. I am having a difficult time navigating Microsoft's website on what SharePoint can actually do.

So my question is, do you guys know which of the above features SharePoint supports? Oh and any recommendations for other document repository solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are targeting SharePoint 2013 on premises;

- Status - this can be done by adding a column to document library
- Workflow - this is available out of the box. You can also enhance workflow capabilities with adding a third party workflow engine (e.g. Nintex)
- Tagging - I am not sure I understand "tagging different sections of a document". Document tags are supported in SharePoint
- Search - supported
- Merging - this is "document set" functionality in SharePoint. But, it is limited to creating a set of documents with multiple files. Not sure this is what you want
- Archiving - Look at records management processes in SharePoint. You can set file retention policies. You can declare records (so no one can change/delete them). Depending upon your definition of Archiving, this may or may not work for you.
- Permissions System - most definitely available. More granular than NTFS IMHO
- Real Time collaboration - available

  Hope this helps

Comment: I have no idea why you were down voted, it is a great answer for me!

What I meant in regards to tagging is basically the comment feature under the Review section in Word. I want to be able to go through a document (be it PDF or Excel) and essentially mark certain paragraphs or sentences with a tag (or really, a comment). I will then want to have the ability to search for these tags/comments.

Comment: As far as I know, SharePoint is not aware of bookmarks/tags within the document. It does provide full text search capability though.